# how to find the affected query in prestashop admin controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prestashop

In prestashop admin controller, we added a filed like bellow to generate the table list view.

```
$this->table        = 'product';
$this->list_id      = 'no_stock_products_attributes';
$this->lang         = true;
$this->identifier   = 'id_product';
$this->_orderBy     = 'id_product';
$this->_orderWay    = 'DESC';
$this->className    = 'Product';
```

I would like to view the final/complete query. Is there any way to get it and will give the runnable query?

like `print_r($this->query());` or like `print_r($this->_query());`

Comment: did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug profiling in /config/defines.inc.php
This will throw a list with all the querys executed, at the bottom of the page.
Beware this also throws a list of querys and technical data in the frontend.